# MySQL to PHP Connection Error in Localhost with Dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql, database, dreamweaver

I Try to access my localhost database which i created with phpmyadmin from dreamweaver. I did successfully setup site and server. I could see my site in the browser with localhost. But when i try to connect from dreamweaver and try to select database it says Your PHP server doens't have the MySQL module loaded or you can't use the mysql_(p)connect functions.

I'm using mac os x el captian and MAMP for the servers.

Thank you for your help

PDO

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql, sqlite, pgsql

in this image i couldn't connect database i can connect with PDO but how can i see the database and bindings in here???

[image]

Comment: Care to add what you are trying?

Comment: What do you mean. i Created a website and try to connect database from dreamweaver. with plus button i could share screen shots.

Comment: use `php_info` on your server and paste the results under mysql / mysqli / pdo as part of your question

Comment: I did that. PDO is enanled

Comment: Then why are you using mysql_* functionality? Use PDO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to echo mysql_error()
This will give you actual connection error details

Comment: but i try to connect with database tab in the dreamweaver. When i try to connect otherways i got nothing

Comment: just simply create one file connect,php and write this code:

<?php

  $con=mysql_connect("host","user","password") or die("Unable to establish connection");

?>

and see what it comes out to be. carefully insert your host, username and password